# ORMLite 5.0 build failure

Tags: android, ormlite

Proguard is failing with warnings when I upgraded to v.50 of ORMLite and ORMLite for Android. My proguard configuration for ORMLite is below:

```
-keep class com.j256.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keep class com.colorsnap.model.**
-keepclassmembers class com.colorsnap.model.** { *; }
```

Logs

```
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Id
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.OneToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Version
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.FetchType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Id
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.OneToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Version
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.FetchType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.FetchType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.EnumType
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Column
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Basic
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Id
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.OneToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.ManyToOne
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.JoinColumn
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Enumerated
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Version
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Entity
Warning: com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find referenced class javax.persistence.Table
```

Comment: I believe these are superfluous warnings, try turning it off by adding `-dontwarn org.slf4j.**` and see if it works.

Answer (score 11):

Adding the following worked for me:

```
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-dontwarn javax.persistence.**
-dontwarn javax.lang.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.tools.**
```

Comment: I think this cannot be accepted because don't warn means you suppressed the error.This can cause some functional problems which can be serious.